# Fetching fact from stateful session of drools

Tags: java, drools

I'm trying to get the new inserted fact from the rules:

```
import com.neu.als.thesis.db.beans.FLTBean
import com.neu.als.thesis.db.beans.StudentBean

rule "Excellent"
    no-loop

    when
        $m: FLTBean ( listeningScore > 85 && listeningScore < 101 )
    then
        StudentBean studentBean = new StudentBean();
        studentBean.setKnowledgeLevel( "Excellent" );
        insert( studentBean );
end
```

To get something from the stateful session I should do this:

```
protected Collection<Object> findFacts( final StatefulKnowledgeSession session, final String factClass )
{
    ObjectFilter filter = new ObjectFilter()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean accept( Object object )
        {
            return object.getClass().equals( factClass );
        }
    };
    Collection<Object> results = session.getObjects( filter );
    return results;
}
```

Given the fact that I already set the code to read the rules the next step I did is this:

```
protected void processFacts( KnowledgeBase aKnowledgeBase, Object aBean )
{
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = aKnowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

    ksession.insert( aBean );
    ksession.fireAllRules();

    Collection<Object> result = findFacts( ksession, "StudentBean" );

    ksession.dispose();

    for( Object test : result )
    {
        System.out.println( test == null );
        System.out.println( test );
    }
}
```

Why I don't get any response from the object? It doesn't print anything. No stacktrace, no error. I even check it if its null. But still no response. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

This is the method that read the .drl file.

```
protected KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase( String aRuleFileName ) throws Exception
{
     KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
     kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource( aRuleFileName, getClass() ), ResourceType.DRL );
     KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();

     if( errors.size() > 0 )
     {
        for( KnowledgeBuilderError error : errors )
        {
            System.err.println( error );
        }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Could not parse knowledge." );
     }

   KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
   kbase.addKnowledgePackages( kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages() );
   return kbase;
}
```

The one that calls the processFacts method is this

```
public String evaluateConceptKnowledgeLevel( double FLTmark )
{
   String knowledgeLevel = null;

   // test
   InferenceEngine ie = new InferenceEngine();
   KnowledgeBase kbase;
   try
   {
       kbase = ie.readKnowledgeBase( "KnowledgeLevel.drl" );
       FLTBean bean = new FLTBean();
       bean.setListeningScore( FLTmark );

       ie.processFacts( kbase, bean );
   }
   catch( Exception e )
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   // up to here

   return knowledgeLevel;
}
```

Comment: Either `result` is empty or the method was never called. Assuming the first, What debugging have you tried in `factFacts()`?

Comment: @clwhisk I S.O.P in the rules with this value `studentBean.getKnowledgeLevel()` and its printing fine. And I'm also sure the the rules are called because of this. I also tried printing the parameters in the `findFacts` method It also have value. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which parameters are you refering to? My only point was that if the return value of `findFacts` is an empty list, this should point you to exactly where to look in that method.

Comment: @clwhisk I was thinking that my mistake is how I print the facts. The parameters that I'm talking about are the parameters of `findFacts` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options...

Pass in the simple name instead of the full class name.

Change

```
Collection<Object> result = findFacts( ksession, "com.neu.als.thesis.db.beans.StudentBean" );
```

to

```
Collection<Object> result = findFacts( ksession, "StudentBean" );
```

Change the 'accept' method to compare the full class name.

Change

```
     public boolean accept( Object object ) {
         return object.getClass().getSimpleName().equals( factClass );
     }
```

to

```
     public boolean accept( Object object ) {
         return object.getClass().getName().equals( factClass );
     }
```

Change the findFacts method to take the actual class as an argument and compare to that.

Change

```
protected Collection<Object> findFacts( 
        final StatefulKnowledgeSession session, 
        final String factClass ) {
    ObjectFilter filter = new ObjectFilter() {
    @Override
        public boolean accept( Object object ) {
            return object.getClass().getSimpleName().equals( factClass );
        }
    };

    Collection<Object> results = session.getObjects( filter );
    return results;
}
```

to

```
protected Collection<Object> findFacts( 
        final StatefulKnowledgeSession session, 
        final Class factClass ) {
    ObjectFilter filter = new ObjectFilter() {
    @Override
        public boolean accept( Object object ) {
            return object.getClass().equals( factClass );
        }
    };

    Collection<Object> results = session.getObjects( filter );
    return results;
}
```

Assuming that your facts are all Java classes, then the 3rd option of comparing the class is a better option. If you use declared types, then the simple name is useful, as you are unlikely to have a reference to the actual class that Drools generates.

An additional note for when you're testing these things, the Drools API also provides the session.getObjects() method with no arguments. By calling that you will get a reference to all facts that are in working memory, no matter what they are. When writing filters, it's not a bad idea to use that to prove to yourself that the expected facts are in working memory, and then to add filtering, so that you can pick out specific facts according to their class and their properties.

Comment: I updated my post. I printed the `session.getObject()` to the `findFacts` method and the result is this `org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl$ObjectStoreWrapper@f886d9` that means there is an object to the session right? But still when I call it from another method with the same loop as I posted above there is no response from the object.

Comment: I want to get the bean that I set from the rules but as you said before I should use this `Collection<Object> results = session.getObjects( filter );` to get the values. But how can I get the bean from there?

Comment: session.getObjects() without a filter gives you a list of all objects in working memory, including the one inserted by your rule. If you use an ObjectFilter argument, then the list of objects returned must match what is in the accept(object) method of your ObjectFilter. Your bean will be returned if it matches the constraints you put in your object filter.

Comment: I see, so if I do this `Collection<Object> result = findFacts( ksession, "StudentBean" );` the Bean is already inside the `result` right? My question is how do I exactly going to get it from there? The collection has no `.get()`. I tried casting it to `Collection<StudentBean>` but still no luck.

Comment: for (Object o : result) { StudentBean student = (StudentBean)o; }

Comment: You need to cast the objects in the collection, not the collection itself.

Comment: Silly me. That's right why did I not think of that. Steve one last. I'm getting an error after I submit the form 6 - 7 times I'm getting `Per Gem Out of memory` how do I fix this. I'm really sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I couldn't say without seeing your rules and the way you call them. You might need to create another question to cover that one. :)