# Inserting a new object to StatelessKnowledgeSession

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I've a simple rule like this:

```
rule "First Rule" //You do not talk about Fight Club
when
    MyInp(id=="1")
then
    insert(new MyOut(true));
end
```

What I want is, getting the created MyOut object from a Java class.
Is there a way to do this or do I have to pass a global variable and update it inside the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a stateless session you can modify a fact which you insert, or register a global which you update.

If you have a stateful session then there are a few more options:

[Fetching fact from stateful session of drools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884847/fetching-fact-from-stateful-session-of-drools/19888360#19888360)

If you're looking for a general means of examining what existed in working memory during your stateless session,

```
StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession = 
        kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
TrackingWorkingMemoryEventListener listener = 
        new TrackingWorkingMemoryEventListener();
ksession.addEventListener(listener);

List<Object> facts = new ArrayList<Object>();
facts.add(myRequestFact);

ksession.execute(facts);

List<ObjectInsertedEvent> insertions = listener.getInsertions();
```

It's handy for debugging and audit purposes, but I wouldn't recommend it as a means of getting the actual results out of a request. Example code (by me) for a tracking WorkingMemoryEventListener can be found here:

https://github.com/gratiartis/sctrcd-payment-validation-web/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sctrcd/drools/util/TrackingWorkingMemoryEventListener.java

Comment: Thanks @Steve. If I understood you correctly, I can't get new objects from Stateless session, am I right?

Comment: No ... you just run the execute() method, which encapsulates creating a stateful (!) session, inserting facts and then terminating that session. So after running, you have no means of querying the session for facts. However, I'll add a quick note on WorkingMemoryEventListener, as that could be used to achieve that goal.

Comment: Ok Steve. I don't like EventListener approach too. So I'll go with inserting an empty message/output object to session beforehand and retrieve it after.

Comment: I think that's the best approach - insert a MyRequest/MyResult pair.